# Can I drive and reverse this motor with an ESC?

Tags: dc-motor, raspberry-pi, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I've just ordered [this motor](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/High-reliability-gear-brushless-dc-motor-planetary-gearbox-ratio-10-1-with-NEMA-23-180W-24V/32797544178.html), which I want to drive and reverse using my Raspberry Pi.

I've successfully used an H-bridge to drive and reverse a brushed DC motor before, but for this motor I think I will need an ESC. So I ordered [this ESC](https://nl.aliexpress.com/item/100-Original-Hot-Sale-FVT-LittleBee-30A-ESC-2-6S-BLHeli-Supports-OneShot125-For-RC-Quadcopter/32662395608.html).

I now wonder; did I do the right thing? Can I drive that motor with that ESC? And can I also reverse that motor with that ESC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the ESC you bought will drive the motor. The motor is 3 phase BLDC.

The only problem you may have is that the ESC is low torque startup (it's designed for a Heli/quad copter. However given the large 10:1 gearbox you may be ok. 
If you need high torque at low starting speeds you really need a BLDC with Hall Effect position sensors

To add from your comment...the new controller you selected is exactly correct for your motor....which already has the Hall Effect sensors fitted.

Comment: I actually do need high torque at low speed. So would something like this be appropriate: https://m.aliexpress.com/s/item/32696060327.html Can I drive that with a Raspberry pi? And can I also use that to reverse the motor?

Comment: @kramer65 Can you find, read, and understand datasheets?  If not, then you'll have to rely on random people on the internet to tell you the details of what you can and can't do, and there's no guarantee of it making sense.  If that's where you are, then you might as well just buy all you can at random and test it...which seems to be what you're doing anyway.

Comment: @AaronD - You're right; reading datasheets and understanding them is the best thing to do. I'm currently more on a level of trial and error, learning by doing and following tutorials (written by "random people on the internet"). I've looked at the ESC and read over a couple articles/tutorials to try to figure it out, but I'm not sure. And so I come to the point that I ask a question here on StackExchange. Answers from (random) helpful people help me a lot, and I don't really understand what the problem is with that. If you don't want to answer that's fine, and if you do, that's awesome!

Comment: @kramer65 It's good that you understand that.  You're a lot farther along than most people that post this kind of thing.  The reason I didn't answer is because I don't think I *can*, beyond having you buy from sites that actually give you a datasheet.  Engineering-oriented sites are not flashy like consumer ones.  They might be more expensive, but at least you know what you're getting.  Even an experienced engineer often can't tell what they're getting on a consumer discount site.

Comment: @AaronD - It took me some time, but I finally managed to understand the datasheets of the motor and the BLDC driver. I drew up a more detailed plan/diagram of how I want to drive it. I asked a question about my plan in which you can hopefully see that I do think about what I do: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/321440/can-i-drive-a-bldc-driver-with-this-diagram